# PDO excpetion SQLSTATE[23000]:in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

i'm using PDo with OOP to insert data into database mysql using xampp , i got error for inserting null values , 
 this code of sql be note the id auto increment  , it works fine

```
     CREATE TABLE `consumer` (

    `Consumer_ID` int(8) NOT NULL,

    `FName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    `LName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    `Email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,

    `Passwords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

    `Gender` char(1) NOT NULL,

    `Birth_Year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,

    `City` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    `Neighborhood` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    `Mobile_Number` int(11) NOT NULL,

    `Contact_Preference` varchar(15) NOT NULL,

    `Status` char(1) DEFAULT 'a',

    `Longitude` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,

     `Latitude` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,

     `Join_Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

     `Last_Login_Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL

      ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

     ALTER TABLE `consumer`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Consumer_ID`),
     ADD UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`Email`);
     ALTER TABLE `consumer`
     MODIFY `Consumer_ID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

this code for connection with database it works fine

```
    <?php
    class  dbconnection{
    Private $server = "localhost";
    Private $database = "*****";
    Private $userName = "*****";
    Private $password = "*****";
    public function connect()   
    {
    try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->server;dbname=$this->database", 
        $this->userName, $this->password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $db;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
    public function disconnect(){
    $db = null;
    return $db;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

consumer class , that has the exception error

```
    <?php
    require 'dbconnection.class.php';
    class consumer
    {
    Public function register($FName,$LName,$Email,$Passwords,$Gender,$Birth_Year,$City,$Neighborhood,$Mobile_Number,$Contact_Preference,$Longitude,$Latitude)
    {
    try 
    {
    $connection = new dbconnection;
    $db = $connection->connect();
    $Query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO consumer(FName,LName,Email,Passwords,Gender,Birth_Year,City,Neighborhood,Mobile_Number,Contact_Preference,Longitude,Latitude) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $Query->bindParam(1,$Fname);
        $Query->bindParam(2,$Lname);
        $Query->bindParam(3,$Email);
        $Query->bindParam(4,$Password);
        $Query->bindParam(5,$Gender);
        $Query->bindParam(6,$Birth_Year);
        $Query->bindParam(7,$City);
        $Query->bindParam(8,$Neighborhood);
        $Query->bindParam(9,$Mobile_Number);
        $Query->bindParam(10,$Contact_Preference);
        $Query->bindParam(11,$Longitude);
        $Query->bindParam(12,$Latitude);
        $Query->execute();
        return $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = $connection->disconnect();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
     }
     }
     }
     $test = new consumer;
     $test->register('ahmed','ahmed','ahmed','ahmed','4','2018','cairo','naser',01121980528,'now',5,9);
     ?>
```

Comment: Try reading the actual error message. You are probably trying insert something, that does not match your table definition ... like for example - phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with variables.
You're defining function parameters as `$FName,$LName`, but you're using `$Fname,$Lname`in query binding.

Variable names are case-sensitive.

`$Passwords` and `$Password` are different too.